# MySQL trigger cannot be invoked

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Creating a trigger is successful

```
mysqli_query($this->conn,
   "CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete_address`
    BEFORE DELETE ON address FOR EACH ROW
    DELETE FROM city WHERE cityid = OLD.cityid");
```

but when I execute the following query

```
DELETE FROM address WHERE addressid = 18
```

it outputs the following error code

```
Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gamecomp`.`address`, CONSTRAINT `cityid` FOREIGN KEY (`cityid`) REFERENCES `city` (`cityid`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)    0.039 sec
```

The constraints on the address table are set to `On Update cascade` and `On Delete restrict`.

The columns of the address table are `addressid, address, cityid, zipcode`, cityid is a FK reference to the city table contains `cityid, city, countryid`

Can someone point out what I have done wrong? thanks

Answer (score 2):

`address FOREIGN KEY (cityid) REFERENCES city (cityid) ON DELETE RESTRICT` means that you may not delete a city that any `address.cityid` references. Since that is exactly what your trigger does, you get a foreign key constraint error.

Even if you make this trigger an `AFTER DELETE ON`, you might still have other address rows that reference a city, which means you might still get a foreign key constraint error. You should also verify that there are no triggers on the `city` table which may be upsetting constraints on foreign keys in `address`.

You need to verify first that all references to the `cityid` are gone before you delete the corresponding `city`. Frankly I'm not convinced you should even be trying to do this. In a well-designed schema, some orphaned records should not be a problem. If they really trouble you they can be deleted with a cronjob periodically instead of with a trigger.

If you insist on a trigger, try this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_city_orphans`
AFTER DELETE ON address FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM city WHERE city.id=OLD.cityid
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM address WHERE cityid=OLD.cityid)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of  BEFORE DELETE ON city use  AFTER DELETE ON address

Comment: Insted of BEFORE add AFTER

Comment: It still outputs the same error. The address table contains only a reference to the city table. Is there something to do with reference constraints?

Comment: have you created trigger with  AFTER DELETE ON address ?

Comment: Yes, I have simply change BEFORE to AFTER

Comment: Can you try by dropping and create trigger again?

Comment: No success even I dropped all triggers